# How to get multiple results from dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is showing all divs if I select councils but when I change to property it only shows the first, but I want to display all divs which contain property ID. I want to display all results which are related to the selection from dropdown menu.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drop Down Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showTab ( name ) {
    name = '#' + name;
    $('div').not(name).hide();
    $(name).show();
  }

  $('#dropdown').change(function () {
    showTab( $( this ).val() );
  });

  showTab( $('#dropdown').val() );
});  // this line was missing 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
      <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value="" selected="selected">All </option>
        <option value="Pubs">Pubs </option>
        <option value="Councils">Councils </option>
        <option value="Property">Property </option>
        <option value="Various">Various </option>
        <option value="Universitys">Universitys </option>
      </select>
      </p>
    </form>

    <div id="Pubs">pubs</div>
    <div id="Councils">councils 1</div>
    <div id="Property">property 1</div>
    <div id="Various">various</div>
    <div id="Councils">councils 2</div>
    <div id="Universitys">universitys</div>
    <div id="Property">property 2</div>
    <div id="Property">property 3</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to display results like this:

If I select Councils then Results will show

```
Councils 1<br>
Councils 2
```

If I select Property the result will show

```
Property 1<br>
Property 2<br>
Property 3
```

If I select Pubs the result will show

```
Pubs
```

Comment: Your code works, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/7p8zga0L/ do you have any console errors where something might be stoping the code from excecuting?

Comment: not meet my requierment.......... help me please

Comment: oh wait, you have duplicate ids, you cant do that, hold on

Comment: You should use classes like this https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/7p8zga0L/1/ ids **must** be unique

Comment: thx brother its working.....